# create dictionary with for loop (python)

Tags: python

```py
cols = 'ABC'
ind = range(3)

value=[]

dic = {}

for c in cols:
        for i in ind:
            value.append(str(c) + str(i))
        dic[c] = value

print(dic)
```

output:

```py
{'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'C0', 'C1', 'C2'], 'B': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'C0', 'C1', 'C2'], 'C': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'C0', 'C1', 'C2']}
```

why am i getting the above output ?

while I want the output to be like

output:

```py
{'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2'], 'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2'], 'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2']}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you used same object `value` for every values.
You should insert `value = []` in the `for c in cols:` block,
But here is more pythonic way:

```py
cols = 'ABC'
ind = range(3)

dic = {
    c: [c + str(i) for i in ind]
    for c in cols
}
print(dic)
```

output:

```py
{'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2'], 'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2'], 'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2']}
```

Comment: I am learning the list and dictionary comprehension, so i was trying to code first in old way. Thank you for highlighting to the reset value.

Answer (score 0):

Thats simple you have to reset you array after each iteration

```
cols = 'ABC'
ind = range(3)
dic = {}
for c in cols:
    value=[]
    for i in ind:
        value.append(str(c) + str(i))
    dic[c] = value
print(dic)
```

Result:

```
{'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2'], 'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2'], 'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2']}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering the question

Answer (score 0):

```
cols = 'ABC'
dic = {c:[c + str(x) for x in range(3)] for c in cols}

print(dic)
```

Output:

```
{'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2'], 'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2'], 'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2']}
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
def make_df(cols, ind):          
    # Create a DataFrame           
    data = {c: [str(c) + str(i) for i in ind] for c in cols}
    return pd.DataFrame(data, ind)

# Example DataFrame       
make_df('ABC', range(3))
```